# Image data augmentation in TF 2.0 -- rotation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I am training a tensorflow model with with multiple images as input and a segmentation mask at the output. I wanted to perform random rotation augmentation in my dataset pipeline.

I have a list of parallel image file names (input output files aligned) for which I convert into tf dataset object using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` and then and use `Dataset.map` function to load images with `tf.image.decode_png` and `tf.io.read_file` commands.

How can I perform random rotations on the input-output images. I tried using `random_transform` function of [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/apply_affine_transform) class but it expects numpy data as input and does not work on Tensors (Since tensorflow does not support eager execution in data pipeline I cannot convert it into numpy as well). I suppose I can use [tf.numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) but I expect there should be some simple solution for this simple problem.

Comment: TensorFlow Addons provide [this option](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/rotate), which might be worth looking into.

Comment: Oh yes I saw that but it does not provide fill mode when we rotate and only fills 0s. There is an [ongoing PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/pull/1719/files) for this though